# ChartJS - How do I remove the X-Axis color overlay on the chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs

I styled the ChartJS X grid lines a specific color, but the X Axis gridline has a default color that overlays the color I styled the grid lines with, does anyone what the reason could be that this is occurring?

Heres the chart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBl9p.png

Heres the code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/igan6.png

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried some approach to your problem that didn't work? If that's the case, can you share it? So it will be easier for someone to solve it. "Here's the chart, here's the code" is less likely to get your question solved.

Comment: Please paste the code here, instead of providing an image.